PromQL: Получить количество запросов у которых время выполнения больше 3 секунд
У меня есть конкретная конечная точка и по нему мне нужно сформировать правильный запрос чтобы получить все запросы за последние 5 минут у которых время выполнения больше 3 секунд и проверить что их количество больше 10
Я использовал следующий запрос но он не работает корректно
count_over_time(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{env=~"myEnv", group="myGroup", uri="myUri", le="3"}[5m]) > 10

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так я делаю?

Ну как минимум le="3" означает «меньше чем три», то есть видимо нужно вычитать метрику le="3" из метрики le="+inf" или что-то типа того

А ещё, кажется, функция count_over_time использована неверно — она считает количество записей метрики, а не значения, записанные в этой метрике, а для работы со значениями метрики видимо нужно использовать что-то вроде rate или increase

В процессе экспериментов я родил такое increase(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{env=~"myEnv", group="myGroup", uri="myUri", le="+Inf"}[5m]) - ignoring(le) group_left() increase(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{env=~"myEnv", group="myGroup", uri="myUri", le="3"}[5m]) (но я не уверен, что творю не дичь, так что воспринимать меня слишком всерьёз не стоит)
